# React Controlled vs Uncontrolled inputs

Tags: reactjs

I followed the React Form tutorial to create the component below:

```
export default class SignInForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }

    this.onEmailChange = this.onEmailChange.bind(this)
    this.onPasswordChange = this.onPasswordChange.bind(this)
  }

  onEmailChange(event) {
    this.setState({email: event.target.value})
  }

  onPasswordChange(password) {
    this.setState({password: event.target.value})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>Email</label>
          <div>
            <input type="email"
              placeholder="you@gmail.com"
              onChange={this.onEmailChange}
              value={this.state.email}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Password</label>
          <div>
            <input type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
              onChange={this.onPasswordChange}
              value={this.state.password}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

As soon as the form renders, I get the following error:

> SignInForm is changing a controlled input of type password to be
>   uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to
>   uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or
>   uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component

I cannot find the place where I am making it an uncontrolled component. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I got this error because I forget to set an initial state for the value, adding this as a comment in case it helps others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your onPasswordChange method should probably be:

```
onPasswordChange(event) {
    this.setState({password: event.target.value})
}
```

Comment: In case there are other poor readers like me: The difference is the OP's function argument (password) should have been (event).