# Keep getting a controlled vs uncontrolled react error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I keep getting this error in my console:

> warning.js?8a56:36 Warning: LoginForm is changing a controlled input
>   of type password to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch
>   from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using
>   a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the
>   component. More info: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

I have had a look at these questions:

- [How to create a controlled input with empty default in React 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37175048/how-to-create-a-controlled-input-with-empty-default-in-react-15) - I define my state already
- [React Controlled vs Uncontrolled inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36586835/react-controlled-vs-uncontrolled-inputs) - My function takes an event and not a password parameter
- [React - changing an uncontrolled input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427508/react-changing-an-uncontrolled-input) - I already define the password as empty

Here is the component:

```
export default class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      values: {
        username: "",
        password: ""
      }
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this._clearInput = this._clearInput.bind(this);
  }

  onSubmit(event) {
    // this.props.attemptLogin
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.values);
    let {username, password} = this.state.values;

    this.props.attemptLogin(username, password)
    .then((userInfo) => {
      console.log(userInfo);
      LocalStore.setJson('api', userInfo.api);
      LocalStore.setJson('user', userInfo.user);

      this._clearInput('username' , 'password');

    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Failed:");
      console.log(err);
      this._clearInput('password');
    });
  }

  _clearInput(...fields) {
    let newValuesState = {};
    fields.forEach((field) => {
      newValuesState[field] = '';
    });
    this.setState({values: newValuesState});
  }

  onChange(event) {
    let name = event.target.name;
    let value = event.target.value;
    this.setState({values: {[name]: value}});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form method="post" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <div><input type="text" name="username" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.values.username}/></div>
          <div><input type="password" name="password" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.values.password}/></div>
          <div><button type="submit">Login</button></div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

LoginForm.propTypes = {
  attemptLogin: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

The code does seem to work but this error pops up in the console and so I can't continue I till I get it to stop appearing. Can anyone see what's I did wrong in the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are nesting the values in `state.values`, your `onChange` function will remove the field not being changed. You could do something like this instead:

```
onChange(event) {
    let name = event.target.name;
    let value = event.target.value;
    let values = {...this.state.values};
    values[name] = value;
    this.setState({values}});
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It makes total sense. Such a lousy mistake on my part.